# Can I have my core logic to update object status in Aspect

Tags: design-patterns, aop, aspectj, aspects

I have a requirement where I will be performing a set of operation in a chain pattern ClassA->ClassB->ClassC by invoking common method action().
Ideally ClassA, ClassB and ClassC implements interface IClass having method action().

At the end of action() method, its status(failed/success) should be updated in the Database.
So my doubt is,
 
 - Is it a good design to leverage Aspect's around advice for method "action" and update the status in Aspect class once the action got executed.
 - Our since it is core logic to update the action status, it shouldn't be part of cross-cutting framework like aspect?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show your code, please. And learn how to ask questions and how to write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think aspect is the right option to implement above behaviour. 
Aspect is a common code which is used across multiple classes / modules.

Typical examples are `transaction management, logging`

The better option could be to write one interface and implementation like below-

```
public interface StatusUpdater{
    updateActionStatus();
}
```

Have one class implement this interface.

```
public class StatusUpdaterImpl implements StatusUpdater{
    updateActionStatus();
}
```

Have this class injected into `Class A , B and C` and delegate the db update to this class.

This you will have flexibility in changing the Db update behaviour if required .

Have one more class implanting `StatusUpdater` interface and inject into target